# How can I allow one specific Google URL through when the whole Google domain is blocked by firewall?

Tags: firewall, url, domain-name, zonealarm, hulu

Using ZoneAlarm "zones" I have **blocked Google** (https://www.google.com) but I need to **allow a Recaptcha** URL (https://www.google.com/recaptcha/enterprise.js)?

I need this to log in to [Hulu](https://www.hulu.com)!

I have blocked many (50+) Google domains and IP addresses so I don't want to have to reconfigure something new from scratch!

Is there some way to add an exception to *allow that one specific Recaptcha URL through the firewall?*

Comment: No one? Any suggestions or even just ideas?

Comment: Is it possible to use another Recaptcha from another domain, with a Greasemonkey or Tampermonkey script or something similar??